# Typescript - To replace the value of a property is it is not the default value

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have 2 objects. The first object A has a default value of 'enabled' for all properties.

```
public A(): any {
    const enabledObject = { enabled: true };
    return {
        property1: enabledObject,
        property2: enabledObject, 
        property3: enabledObject,
        property4: enabledObject,
    };
}
```

The second object has different properties

```
public B(): any {
    const appProperty = { 
        property1: { enabled: true },
        property2: { enabled: false}, 
        property3: { enabled: true },
        property4: { enabled: false},
    };
}
```

I want to return object A minus any properties that are specified to be 'enabled=false' in object B.

```
public A(): any {
    const enabledObject = { enabled: true };
    return {
        property1: enabledObject, 
        property3: enabledObject,
    };
}
```

I am attempting to fix this with the following but it does not work.

```
return _.assignInWith(A, B, this.Disabled);

private Disabled(destination: any, source: any, key: any): any {
    const disabledObject = { enabled: false };
    if (_.isUndefined(destination)) {
        return disabledObject;
    }
    return destination;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a simple solution without using `lodash`:

```
function AmB(): any {
  const a = A();
  const b = B();
  const res = {};
  for (let aKey in a) {
    if (!b[aKey] || b[aKey].enabled) {
      res[aKey] = a[aKey];
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

[Stackblitz demo of this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-d93i1z?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know loadash syntax, this could be easily done through JavaSscript (or converted to Typescript)

```
   var enabledObject = { enabled: true };
    var A = {
      property1: enabledObject,
      property2: enabledObject, 
      property3: enabledObject,
      property4: enabledObject
    };

    var B = {
      property1: { enabled: true },
      property2: { enabled: false}, 
      property3: { enabled: true },
      property4: { enabled: false}
    };


    var diff = {};
    for(var p in A){
        //diff[p] = {};
      //if B does not have the property, add it to result and continue
      if (!B.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        diff[p] = A[p];

      } else {
        if(B[p].hasOwnProperty('enabled') && !B[p]['enabled']) {
            diff[p] = A[p];
        }
      }
    }
```

just run this code on the console of your browser and print diff variable

If you wanted to, you could further generalize the logic to compare two object with different structure and return the differences

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the following using lodash as follows:

```
function AmB(): any {
 const a = A();
 const b = B();

 const bPairs = _.toPairs(b);
 const bNotEnabled = _.filter(bPairs, bPair => { return !bPair[1].enabled });
 const aPairs = _.toPairs(a);
 const aMinusB = _.reject(aPairs, aPair => _.find(bNotEnabled, b => b[0] === aPair[0]));
 return {...aMinusB}
}
```

And you can see this working [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zj6gl5)